# How can I catch java.net.SocketException when ActiveMQ is stopped?

Tags: java, apache, queue, activemq-classic

I have a consumer Java app which connects to an Apache ActiveMQ server. It's working. However, if I stop the Apache ActiveMQ server the consumer app has an exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

How can I handle this Exception, for example I'd like to send an alert e-mail to support. How can I detect offline ActiveMQ server.

[Here is the exception details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk3O2.png)

```
// Getting JMS connection from the server
ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(this.activeMqClient.getUsername(), this.activeMqClient.getPassword(), this.activeMqClient.getProducerUri());
activeMQConnectionFactory.setUseAsyncSend(false);
activeMQConnectionFactory.setMaxThreadPoolSize(1);

this.activeMqClient.setClientId(activeMqClient.getClientType() + "_" + Thread.currentThread().getName());

if (this.activeMqClient.getClientId() != null) {
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setClientID(this.activeMqClient.getClientId());
}

Connection connection = activeMQConnectionFactory.createConnection();

if (this.activeMqClient.getClientId() != null) {
    connection.setClientID(this.activeMqClient.getClientId());
}

connection.start();

connection.setExceptionListener(this);

// Creating session for receiving messages
Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

// Getting the queue
Destination destination = session.createQueue(this.activeMqClient.getDestinationQueueName() + "?consumer.exclusive=true");

// MessageConsumer is used for receiving (consuming) messages          
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

//Setting message listener
consumer.setMessageListener(this);
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of your code please

Comment: Yes, I edited this question with connection build code

Comment: Was this exception thrown to your client code? If so, why can't you just catch it and then do whatever you need to do (e.g. send an alert e-mail to support)?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch it like any other exception:

```
try {
  //... client code ...//
}
catch(SocketException e) {
  //... send email ...//
}
```